# How to auto start a service if the server restarts

Tags: server, ssh

If I run the command

```
sudo service --status-all
```

all my services come up. I need 1 particular service to start in event of the server restarting please can you tell me the command?

```
service spls
```

Also, is there a way I can remotely log into the server without using putty but a GUI app?

I am using Ubuntu 3.8.0-44 UTC 2014

Comment: i) please ask only one question per post; ii) the command you show prints the status of the service, it doesn't start anything. What do you want to do? iv) there's no such thing as Ubuntu 3.8.0-44 UTC 2014, what Ubuntu version are you using? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: To add to @terdon's reply, there's `vino` which  you can explore for your GUI remote connectivity if there's nothing already installed - it may already be there. If not, it's easy to install. Then you can just pick a client/viewer and connect that way. If you have a specific question about it then ask that question in a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

> I need 1 particular service to start in event of the server restarting please can you tell me the command?

The question really depends on your Ubuntu version. If you have 15.04 and newer with `systemd`, it is straightforward action:

```
systemctl enable service_name
```

for other services, it may differ since the system is still using `init` scripts.

> Also, is there a way I can remotely log into the server without using putty but a GUI app?

There are some. But you will be probably looking for something like VNC.